# Why is my root view controller in the wrong orientation if the iPad is rotated while a modal view controller is displayed?

Tags: ios4, uiinterfaceorientation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a simple view controller that is the root view controller in my application's `UIWindow`. At some point, I have the root view controller present a modal view controller. Nothing special.

However, if I then rotate the device while the modal view controller is displayed, and then dismiss that modal view controller, the original root view controller is in the wrong orientation.

Since Apple removed the ability to set an orientation (e.g., `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:myOrientation]`), I'm at a loss as to how I can force the root view controller to be in the correct orientation when I dismiss the modal view controller that it displays.

Any ideas? Or am I stuck in the depths of iOS orientation hell?

*For the record: the modal view controller is presented **by** the root view controller. I've read somewhere that this helps - it doesn't.*

Comment: I have the same problem - except that it's the detail view geometry that is blown when the modal view is dismissed. Did you find a solution to this? Thanks! David

Comment: I have the same problem, DelMonte...